# Bi-Dimensional array Tic Tac Toe AI Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, tic-tac-toe

I want to make a tic tac toe game with array, not heuristic or tree structure.

for that is there any algorithm that you can tell of "likely AI"? not necessarily ai but the computer choosen spot.

Thanks.

Comment: You're asking for an algorithm that chooses the best spot for the computer to move?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366858/artificial-intelligence-in-tic-tac-toe-using-c-sharp)