# Minimax algorithm for Tic Tac Toe

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, minimax

I'm trying to implement minimax algorithm by Jason Fox (http://neverstopbuilding.com/minimax), but it isn't working, the computer is just making moves randomly. Here is the `Game` class I wrote (I had to create a `cloneGrid` function because arrays were getting passed as references, is there a better way to overcome this problem? ) :

```
class Game
{ 
    public enum Piece { Empty = 0, X = 1, O = 2 };

    static int[,] winConditions = new int[8, 3]
    {
        { 0, 1, 2 }, { 3, 4, 5 }, { 6, 7, 8 },
        { 0, 3, 6 }, { 1, 4, 7 }, { 2, 5, 8 },
        { 0, 4, 8 }, { 2, 4, 6 }
    };

    public Piece[] Grid = new Piece[9];

    public Piece CurrentTurn = Piece.X;

    int Choice = 0;

    public Piece Computer;
    public Piece Player;

    public Game()
    {
        CurrentTurn = Piece.X;
        Player = Piece.X;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        CurrentTurn = Piece.X;
        SetPlayer(Piece.X);
        Grid = new Piece[9];
    }

    public void SetPlayer(Piece Player)
    {
        this.Player = Player;
        this.Computer = switchPiece(Player);
    }

    public void MakeMove(int Move)
    {
        if(CurrentTurn == Player)
        {
            Grid = makeGridMove(Grid, CurrentTurn, Move);
            CurrentTurn = switchPiece(CurrentTurn);
        }
        else if(CurrentTurn == Computer)
        {
            minimax(cloneGrid(Grid), CurrentTurn);
            Grid = makeGridMove(Grid, CurrentTurn, Choice);
            CurrentTurn = switchPiece(CurrentTurn);
            Console.WriteLine(Choice.ToString());
        }
    }

    int minimax(Piece[] InputGrid, Piece Player)
    {
        Piece[] Grid = cloneGrid(InputGrid);

        if (checkScore(Grid, Player) != 0)
            return checkScore(Grid, Player);
        else if (checkGameEnd(Grid)) return 0;

        List<int> scores = new List<int>();
        List<int> moves = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            if (Grid[i] == Piece.Empty)
            {
                scores.Add(minimax(makeGridMove(Grid, Player, i), switchPiece(Player)));
                moves.Add(i);
            }
        }

        if(Player == Computer)
        {
            int MaxScoreIndex = scores.IndexOf(scores.Max());
            Choice = moves[MaxScoreIndex];
            return scores.Max();
        }
        else
        {
            int MinScoreIndex = scores.IndexOf(scores.Min());
            Choice = moves[MinScoreIndex];
            return scores.Min();
        }
    }

    static int checkScore(Piece[] Grid, Piece Player)
    {
        if (checkGameWin(Grid, Player)) return 10;

        else if (checkGameWin(Grid, switchPiece(Player))) return -10;

        else return 0;
    }

    static bool checkGameWin(Piece[] Grid, Piece Player)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            if
            (
                Grid[winConditions[i, 0]] == Player &&
                Grid[winConditions[i, 1]] == Player &&
                Grid[winConditions[i, 2]] == Player
            )
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    static bool checkGameEnd(Piece[] Grid)
    {
        foreach (Piece p in Grid) if (p == Piece.Empty) return false;
        return true;
    }

    static Piece switchPiece(Piece Piece)
    {
        if (Piece == Piece.X) return Piece.O;
        else return Piece.X;
    }

    static Piece[] cloneGrid(Piece[] Grid)
    {
        Piece[] Clone = new Piece[9];
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) Clone[i] = Grid[i];

        return Clone;
    }

    static Piece[] makeGridMove(Piece[] Grid, Piece Move, int Position)
    {
        Piece[] newGrid = cloneGrid(Grid);
        newGrid[Position] = Move;
        return newGrid;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Artificial Intelligence in Tic-Tac-Toe using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366858/artificial-intelligence-in-tic-tac-toe-using-c-sharp)

Comment: @JuanM.Elosegui - No, that's not a dupe at all. Just the same subject.

Comment: don't get me wrong it's an interesting question but basically we have to either play debugger in our head or copy&paste it and use the debugger on machine - so before we do so: *have you stepped through your code with the debugger? And if yes: any hint where the problem is?*

Comment: @talhaLodhi - you have a choice: learn to use the Debugger or learn to write Unit tests.

Comment: @Carsten not much familiar with using the debugger, but i tried adding debug code by using console.writeline to check score values, which was too slow as its a recursive function, though from that, i did notice that mostly all the scores are -10, with very few zeros, and no 10s, also, do you know any good video tuts on debugging in VS, and unit testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is dumb, but the mistake is that i was checking the score w.r.t the current player, but it should only be checked w.r.t the AI. so the solution is to use: checkScore(Grid, Computer), not checkScore(Grid, Player)

Answer (score 0):

This is great, thank you so much. I had to change the code a bit for the algorithm to work correctly for me. So i'm posting here what I did.

```
    static currentPlayer;

    static float minimax(int[,] board, bool isMinimizing)
    {

        int[,] copy = board.Clone() as int[,];

        //if I won - > return 10
        if (isWinner(currentPlayer, copy))
            return 10f;
       // if opponent won - > return -10
        if (isWinner(OtherPlayer(currentPlayer), copy))
            return -10f;
        // if no moves left - > return 0
        if (isFull(copy))
            return 0;

        List<float> scores = new List<float>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                if (copy[i, j] == -1)
                {
                    copy[i, j] = isMinimizing? currentPlayer : OtherPlayer(currentPlayer);
                    float score = minimax(copy, !isMinimizing);
                    copy[i, j] = -1;
                    scores.Add(score);
                }
            }
        }
        if (isMinimizing)
            return scores.Max();

        return scores.Min();

    }
```

Comment: Minor performance point: It seems to me that you don't need to copy the board here - you only change a position if it's -1, and you reset it again after the recursive call.